# Pageblocktable is not rendering

Tags: apex, visualforce, ajax

I'm not able to render the pageblocktable i have set flag in controller and used that flag in vfpage rendered  attribute but its not working

Controller

```
public class wrapperclass {

    public List<account> acc {get;set;}
    public List<contact> con {get;set;}
    public account a {get;set;}
    public boolean b {get;set;}


    public list<wrapper> wrap=new List<wrapper>();

    public list<wrapper> getContacts(){

    String accid=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    a=[select id,name from account where id=:accid];
    con=[select id,name,email from contact where accountid=:accid];
        if(con.size()!=0)
        {
            b=true;
        }
        else
        {
            b=false;
        }
     for(Contact c:con)
     {
         wrap.add(new wrapper(c.id,c.name,c.email));
     }
    return wrap;
    }



}
```

vf page

```
<apex:page controller="wrapperclass">
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockTable  value="{!Contacts}" var="w" rendered="{!b}">
            <apex:column headerValue="Related Contacts"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="{!a.name}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!w.id}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!w.name}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!w.email}"/>

        </apex:pageBlockTable> 


   </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Is your pageblocktable not rendering or are you not able to see any records in pageblocktable ?

Comment: While testing your page you may be missing passing the Id parameter in query header? should be like `/apex/PageName?Id={recordId}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PageBlockTable` is not rendered because when the page is loaded the value of `boolean` is `null` and your PageBlockTable renders only when the `boolean's` value is set to `true`. So this is how the flow would be

- Your controller's constructor would be called which you currently don't have, hence the value of `boolean` `b` would be `null`, at this stage your pageblocktable will not render.
- Your `getter` methods will be called which in your case is `getContacts`, here you are setting the value of `boolean` `b` to `true` if the size if not equal to zero. Now although the `boolean` is set to `true`, as `PageBlockTable` was not rendered when page loaded, this component wouldn't be shown because you are not re-rendering it and there is no component which was rendered on page load to re-render.

So in order for your code to work, it would be easier for you to use the constructor instead of using getter methods.

Replace below code

```
public list<wrapper> wrap=new List<wrapper>();
```

with

```
public list<wrapper> wrap {get;set;}
```

Add constructor in your controller which will initialize the wrapper instance and call the method which sets up the wrapper instance.

```
public wrapperclass(){
    wrap = new List<Wrapper>();
    getContacts();
}
```

Finally, replace the below code in visualforce page

```
<apex:pageBlockTable  value="{!Contacts}" var="w" rendered="{!b}">
```

with

```
<apex:pageBlockTable  value="{!wrap}" var="w" rendered="{!b}">
```

Comment: Thank you it works

Comment: Glad to help you